# Could not infer type for

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire, swifty-json

I am creating a Web API to fetch the data from server and using AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON.

Why the error arises "Could not infer type for 
i) 'address' used within its own type 
ii) Use of unresolved identifier 'userAddress(addressJSON:)'
"
Please help me how to resolve this error ?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class user {

    var name = String()
    var uname = String()
    var email = String()
    var phone = String()
    var address = userAddress?()
    var company = userCompany?()

    init(userJSON : JSON) {
        self.name = userJSON["name"].stringValue
        self.uname = userJSON["username"].stringValue
        self.phone = userJSON["phone"].stringValue
        self.email = userJSON["email"].stringValue

        self.address = userAddress(addressJSON:userJSON["address"])
        self.company = userCompany(companyJSON:userJSON["company"])
    }

}

class userAddress {

    var street = String()
    var city = String()

    init(addressJSON: JSON) {

        self.street = addressJSON["street"].stringValue
        self.city = addressJSON["city"].stringValue
    }
}

class userCompany {

    var companyName = String()
    var phrase = String()

    init(companyJSON: JSON) {

        self.companyName = companyJSON["name"].stringValue
        self.phrase = companyJSON["catchPhrase"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all struct and class names are supposed to start with a capital letter

Your code implies that the JSON provides all values so there are no optionals.

If there is an initializer it's very bad habit to declare the properties with default values. Declaring `var name : String` is perfectly fine.

```
class User {

    var name : String
    var uname : String
    var email : String
    var phone : String
    var address : UserAddress
    var company : UserCompany

    init(userJSON : JSON) {
        self.name = userJSON["name"].stringValue
        self.uname = userJSON["username"].stringValue
        self.phone = userJSON["phone"].stringValue
        self.email = userJSON["email"].stringValue

        self.address = UserAddress(addressJSON:userJSON["address"])
        self.company = UserCompany(companyJSON:userJSON["company"])
    }

}

class UserAddress { ...

class UserCompany { ...
```

Note:

In Swift 4 `JSONDecoder` is much more convenient than `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: can you explain more declare this `var name = String` instead `var name = String()` ?

Comment: If an initial value of a property is assigned in an `init` method it's sufficient (and recommended) to declare only the type. It fulfills the rule *Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created.* You can even declare the property as constant `let name : String`

Comment: @vadian Why do think so? **In Swift 4 JSONDecoder is much more convenient than SwiftyJSON**

Comment: @NazmulHasan because parsing JSON into structs is built-in when using `JSONDecoder`. The entire code can be reduced immensely.